# The flutter_timezone package does not work on Androids below 8

Tags: android, dart, timezone

I want to display a notification in Flutter,
I want to give it time for the show now.
But the flutter_timezone package works well on higher Androids, but it does not work on Android 8 and below.
This is my method:
[image]

I used the flutter_native_timezone package to solve this problem but when I run it I get the following error and I can't run the project.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_native_timezone_updated_gradle'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_native_timezone_updated_gradle:classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle-4.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.1/gradle-4.2.1.jar
   > Could not find builder-4.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:4.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/4.2.1/builder-4.2.1.jar
   > Could not find aaptcompiler-4.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:4.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aaptcompiler/4.2.1/aaptcompiler-4.2.1.jar
   > Could not find manifest-merger-27.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:27.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/27.2.1/manifest-merger-27.2.1.jar
   > Could not find lint-model-27.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:27.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-model/27.2.1/lint-model-27.2.1.jar
   > Could not find aapt2-proto-4.2.1-7147631.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:4.2.1-7147631).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/4.2.1-7147631/aapt2-proto-4.2.1-7147631.jar
   > Could not find gradle-api-4.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:4.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/4.2.1/gradle-api-4.2.1.jar
   > Could not find annotations-27.2.1.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:27.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/27.2.1/annotations-27.2.1.jar
```

How can I solve this problem?
Please pay attention to line 341, I have a problem here